# How to set up a dataqbase connection between MircroStrategy and OpenEdge 11.5 developer Studio

Tags: database-connection, openedge, microstrategy

Would someone kindly help me. I need to set up a db connection between OpenEdge Developer version 11.5 and Microstrategy. I have managed to set up a DNS and a connection between sql server and Microstrategy however struggling with progress. Any information would be of great help Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and install the "SQL Client Access" software from Progress ESD / Download center. It's free but you need to check license key and serial before installing (available at the same place as the download).

Make sure you install 32 or 64-bit drivers (depending on what Microstrategy needs).

[Here's a knowledgebase entry describing more.](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P88405)

Once this is done you'll also have to make sure that your database supports sql-like connections and not (only) 4GL. You can do this by adding the flag

```
-ServerType Both
```

or

```
-ServerType SQL
```

to the your database startup (proserve) script (or by changing in OE Management). "Both" means that both 4GL and SQL logins are accepted. SQL means only SQL.

You can also set up a secondary login broker for this purpose. [Read here for more information.](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P7843)

Comment: Hello,  I have tried to install SQL Client Acess software however since I am using an Evaluation version I don't have access to this. Is there any other way I can proceed.

Comment: Get in touch with Progress directly, they can most likely set you up with an evaluation of the drivers as well...

Comment: Hey Jensd, so far I figured that i needed drivers before any connection can be done so for that , I have Installed DataDirect tool provided from progress It will provide odbc drivers it too is an eval version. From hereforth would you know how i can proceed in making a connection with Microstrategy

Comment: That should be a normal ODBC-setup in the control panel. There should be drivers available there now. You need to add some information about your db (name, port etc).